# Extracting Data from anchor tags using regex in python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract the hyperlinks from a webpage using [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in Python.

suppose my text string is:

```
text = '<a href="/status/ALL">ALL</a></td>/n<a href="/status/ASSIGN">ASSIGN</a></td>'
```

and I want to extract ALL and ASSIGN,
I'm using this regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'<a href=.*>(\w+)</a>', text, re.DOTALL)
```

this just returns ASSIGN.

Can someone please help me in pointing out the mistake in the regular expression? I'm really new to this topic.

Comment: Any reason you can't use an HTML parser? Seeing as you are trying to parse HTML.

Comment: Won't using that seem like overkill for such a small task?

Comment: No, it's a tool for the job. A regex might work sometimes, but it's a bad way to do it. Use a tool designed to do what you want, and you'll have far fewer issues.

Comment: @aman_gupta_052 what if the HTML used other attributes (eg `name`, `id`, `target`) before the `href`? Valid, but your regex would fail. As Lattyware says, use the right tool for the job.

Comment: If anyone cares, I think I got what was wrong with the Regex, i have make the star lazy and not greedy. The greedy star just goes till the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a regular expression, and matching XML with such expressions get [too complicated, too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Please don't make it hard on yourself and use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('a'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```